# How to set Query Parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ezapi

How to map the OLE DB source SQL command query parameters with variables using EzAPI ?
Basically I need to do something like below.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I had to do it for SSIS 2012.  I had to find the GUID of the variable in question and set it that way.

```
EzOleDbSource source = new EzOleDbSource(this);
source.Connection = sourceconnection;
source.SqlCommand = sourcecomannd;
source.AccessMode = AccessMode.AM_SQLCOMMAND;
source.SetComponentProperty("ParameterMapping", "\"Parameter0:Input\",{C2BCD5B0-1FDB-4A74-8418-EEF9C1D19AC3};");
```

To get the GUID you can query the Variables in the EZPackage object.

```
Application a = new Application();
var package = a.LoadPackage(packagelocation, null);
var ezpackage = new EzPackage(package);
var firstOrDefault = ezpackage.Variables.OfType<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable>()
    .AsQueryable()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("MyParameter"));
if (firstOrDefault != null)
{
    var guid =
        firstOrDefault.ID;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to find the GUID of the variable dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

<del>I have accepted Geek's answer because it is the real answer for my question. But I found instead of mapping variables to parameters we can use variables directly in the query. For example: `exec your_sp_name "@[User::your_variable_name]"`</del>

**UPDATE :** Above method is not working.

Use the the accepted answer method. To take the GUID of the variable, I used the follwing method.

```
string guid = string.Empty;

foreach (var x in this.Variables)
{
    if (x.Name == "cdc_capture_log_id")
    {
        guid = x.ID;
    }
}
```

Where `this = EzPackage`. Same as above.